# How to manipulate paired dataset in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

My data looks something like this (a simplified version):

```
df <- read.table(text="cohort,med1,med2,med3,meq1,meq2,meq3
a,drugA,drugB,NA,4.3,1.9,NA
b,drugB,drugC,drugA,2.1,2.0,4.5
a,drugC,NA,NA,2.0,NA,NA
a,drugA,drugB,NA,5.5,3.6,NA
b,drugB,drugA,drugC,4.9,4.1,4.1", sep=",", header=TRUE)

## > df
##   cohort  med1  med2  med3 meq1 meq2 meq3
## 1      a drugA drugB  <NA>  4.3  1.9   NA
## 2      b drugB drugC drugA  2.1  2.0  4.5
## 3      a drugC  <NA>  <NA>  2.0   NA   NA
## 4      a drugA drugB  <NA>  5.5  3.6   NA
## 5      b drugB drugA drugC  4.9  4.1  4.1
```

Each of the `med` values is paired with each of the `meq` values (e.g. the value of `meq1` is the value for that instance of `med1`). How can I restructure the data to be grouped by `med` and by `cohort` and get both the count of `med` and average value of `meq`?

For example:

```
cohort  med    meq
a       drugA  4.9
a       drugB  2.75
a       drugC  2.0
b       drugA  4.3
b       drugB  4.5
b       drugC  3.05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's a `tidyr` way:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- read.table(text ="
cohort med1   med2   med3   meq1   meq2   meq3
a      drugA  drugB  NA     4.3    1.9    NA
b      drugB  drugC  drugA  2.1    2.0    4.5
a      drugC  NA     NA     2.0    NA     NA
a      drugA  drugB  NA     5.5    3.6    NA
b      drugB  drugA  drugC  4.9    4.1    4.1
", header = TRUE)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("me"), 
               names_to = c(".value", "m"),
               names_pattern = "(me(?:d|q))(\\d)")
```

This first step groups the multiple observations per row (med and meq for each of 1, 2, and 3)

```r
print(df_long)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    cohort m     med     meq
#>    <fct>  <chr> <fct> <dbl>
#>  1 a      1     drugA   4.3
#>  2 a      2     drugB   1.9
#>  3 a      3     <NA>   NA  
#>  4 b      1     drugB   2.1
#>  5 b      2     drugC   2  
#>  6 b      3     drugA   4.5
#>  7 a      1     drugC   2  
#>  8 a      2     <NA>   NA  
#>  9 a      3     <NA>   NA  
#> 10 a      1     drugA   5.5
#> 11 a      2     drugB   3.6
#> 12 a      3     <NA>   NA  
#> 13 b      1     drugB   4.9
#> 14 b      2     drugA   4.1
#> 15 b      3     drugC   4.1
```

Then we can take the mean of each drug for each cohort:

```r
df_long %>%
  group_by(cohort, med) %>%
  summarize(meq = mean(meq))
#> Warning: Factor `med` contains implicit NA, consider using
#> `forcats::fct_explicit_na`
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   cohort [2]
#>   cohort med     meq
#>   <fct>  <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 a      drugA  4.9 
#> 2 a      drugB  2.75
#> 3 a      drugC  2   
#> 4 a      <NA>  NA   
#> 5 b      drugA  4.3 
#> 6 b      drugB  3.5 
#> 7 b      drugC  3.05
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Not only does this help me with this particular data set, but also other similar ones I encounter at work.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Although you could do this using `tidyr::pivot_longer`, you can reshape your data fairly easily in base R like this:

```r
f   <- function(df, index) setNames(df[,index], c("cohort", "med", "meq"))
df2 <- rbind(f(df, c(1, 2, 5)), f(df, c(1, 3, 6)), f(df, c(1, 4, 7)))
df2 <- df2[!is.na(df2$med),]
df2
#>    cohort   med meq
#> 1       a drugA 4.3
#> 2       b drugB 2.1
#> 3       a drugC 2.0
#> 4       a drugA 5.5
#> 5       b drugB 4.9
#> 6       a drugB 1.9
#> 7       b drugC 2.0
#> 9       a drugB 3.6
#> 10      b drugA 4.1
#> 12      b drugA 4.5
#> 15      b drugC 4.1
```

You can then get a count of drugs like this:

```r
table(df2$med)

#> drugA drugB drugC 
#>     4     4     3
```

And a mean of `meq` like this:

```
mean(df2$meq)
#> [1] 3.545455

tapply(df2$meq, df2$med, mean)
#> drugA drugB drugC 
#> 4.600 3.125 2.700
```